# Open webbrowser in background in Python

Tags: python

How can I open a URL with my default webbrowser in the background without changing window focus?

In other words I want to stay in the terminal while opening the webbrowser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import locale
from decimal import Decimal
import re
import time
import threading
import os
import webbrowser
import urllib
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint


url='https://www.google.com'
webbrowser.open(url)
```

I am trying this codes

```
webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)
```

or

```
webbrowser.open(url, new=1, autoraise=True)
```

or

```
webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=True)
```

But doesn't work this codes and i trying also

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)
```

or

```
webbrowser.open_new(url)
```

doesn't work again.

My python version 3.6.4 and using windows10

Comment: It's impossible to get  this AttributeError because you never called new_tab, definitely not in your code you show us here! You should edit your question...

Comment: `webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)` works perfectly fine on my machine (also Windows 10). This seems to be a problem with your computer rather than the Python module.

Comment: Are you using a wsl, venv or anything else that might cause trouble? Try to produce a minimum reproducible exammple (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) i.e. don't import any other libraries etc.

Comment: i reduced the codes. "import webbrowser   URL='https://www.google.com'
webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL) " but my screen is showing the page.i  want it to not show. just need the stay

Comment: i need help my friends